# IRandomAccessStream Vs Streams

Tags: c#, windows, stream

I see `IRandomAccessStream` being used in a windows app. What benefit this stream provides compared to other streams like `FileStream`, `MemoryStream`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are used in different frameworks - `IRandomAccessStream` is an interface used in Windows Runtime, `FileStream` and `MemoryStream` are classes used in .NET.

You can convert between them with extension methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531021(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks. But, MemoryStream can still be used in a situation reading an image into.

Comment: aren't Windows Store apps (WinRT) part of the .NET framework? I just assumed whenever I'm writing code in C# using Visual Studio, I'm using the .NET framework.

Comment: @Backwards_Dave No, WinRT is at its core a native framework, not a managed one (it is designed so C++ code can access it). However as part of its construction WinRT objects can be easily accessed from .NET. Microsoft has also provided some additional niceties for writing .NET apps which access WinRT APIs.